# For loop in self calling Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, for-loop

In my JS code i have a function that needs to call itself, which contains a for loop, but even tho i used `let` instead of `var`, my variable will never go over 0

```
function evalScr(id){
  if(id == undefined){
    id="CodeInput";
  }
  ChildArray = $("#"+id).children();
  for(let i=0;i <= ChildArray.length-2;i++){
    console.log(i)
    MainArr.push(ChildArray[i].id)
    if(ChildArray[i].classList.contains("Loop") == true){
      evalScr(ChildArray[i].id)
    }

  }
}
```

Did i do some stupid mistake or is this simply not possible in this way?

Help would be greatly apprechiated!

Comment: You forgot to declare `ChildArray`. There's no reason to re-fetch the element from the DOM if you've already got a reference to it.

Comment: Does `childArray` have 2 or more children?

Comment: @Pointy, there is a need to re fetch the element, because it calls itself with different elements (Child elements of the ChildArray before)   EDIT: Thank you pointy for asking, i think my mistake was that the ChildArray variable doesnt have the right 'scope' (eg. it's the same variable that gets changed when the function gets called, if that makes sense :P)